# Problem with inserting new record to sqlite in android studio

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to insert a new record into a sqlite db.
My table is called `words`. It has the columns `id`, `word`, `meaning`, `details`, `lesson`, `ticks`.

When I try to insert a new record, it just saves `details` as `word` and `lesson` as `meaning`, whereas `details` and `lesson` are stored with a null value.
The autoincrement primary key `id` and `ticks` are stored correctly.

---

## Code

#### Handler:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
protected static final String DATABASE_NAME = "wordDatabase";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String sql = "CREATE TABLE words " +
            "( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "word TEXT, " +
            "meaning TEXT, " +
            "details TEXT, " +
            "lesson TEXT, " +
            "ticks INTEGER ) ";
    db.execSQL(sql);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS words";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

#### Object:

```
    public class ObjectStudent {
        int id;
        String word;
        String meaning;
        String details;
        String lesson;
        int ticks;

    public ObjectStudent(){

    }
```

#### OnClickListener:

```
public class OnClickeListenerCreateStudent implements View.OnClickListener {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    final Context context = view.getRootView().getContext();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View formElementsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_input_form, null, false);

    final EditText et_word = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.et_word);
    final EditText et_meaning = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.et_meaning);
    final EditText et_details = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.et_details);
    final EditText et_lesson = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.et_lesson);


    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setView(formElementsView)
            .setTitle("Create Word")
            .setPositiveButton("Add",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            String wordTitle = et_word.getText().toString();
                            String wordMeaning = et_meaning.getText().toString();
                            String wordDetails = et_details.getText().toString();
                            String wordLesson = et_lesson.getText().toString();

                            ObjectStudent objectStudent = new ObjectStudent();
                          /*  objectStudent.word= wordTitle;
                            objectStudent.meaning= wordMeaning;
                            objectStudent.details= wordDetails;
                            objectStudent.lesson= wordLesson;*/
                            objectStudent.word = "word"; // et_word.getText().toString();
                            objectStudent.meaning = "meaning"; // et_meaning.getText().toString();
                            objectStudent.details = "details"; // et_details.getText().toString();
                            objectStudent.lesson = "lesson"; // et_lesson.getText().toString();

                            objectStudent.ticks= 1;

                            boolean createSuccessful = new TableControllerStudent(context).create(objectStudent);

                            if(createSuccessful){
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Word information was saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to save Word information.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            ((MainActivity) context).countRecords();
                            ((MainActivity) context).readRecords();



                            dialog.cancel();
                        }

                    }).show();
}
```

#### Create method on `TableControllerStudent` class:

```
public class TableControllerStudent extends DatabaseHandler {

public TableControllerStudent(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public boolean create(ObjectStudent objectStudent) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


  /*  values.put("word", objectStudent.word);
    values.put("meaning", objectStudent.meaning);
    values.put("details", objectStudent.details);
    values.put("lesson", objectStudent.lesson);*/

    values.put("word", "w");
    values.put("meaning", "m");
    values.put("details", "d");
    values.put("lesson", "l");

    values.put("ticks", objectStudent.ticks);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + "words "+ "(word, meaning,details, lesson, ticks ) VALUES ('word','meaning','details','lesson',2)");

    //boolean createSuccessful = db.insert("words", null, values) > 0;
    db.close();

    //return createSuccessful;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I do some method to insert they work correctly but hte problem is by the db Ithink.

Answer (score 1):

Just update Database version to higher version(instead of 1,use 5).And check it.before run the application ,please uninstall and then run.

Comment: Hi, I did but nothing changed. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use

`db.insert(YOUR_TABLE_NAME,values);`

instead of

`db.execSQL()` function